# How to configure disk for volumes for Longhorn

Tags: longhorn

How to configure disk for volumes for Longhorn during installation?
Not in GUI please!

I have a couple of Kubernetes nodes with large disks. Disk is mounted at `/var/lib/data/`

How to configure Longhorn at installation to use this  `/var/lib/data/` only?

I tried to use helm chart with `values.yml` like this. It does not work. Volumes are placed at `/var/lib/longhorn/`

```
defaultSettings:
  defaultDataPath: /var/lib/data/
```

Comment: Asumming Longhorn was not already running in your cluster when you added the nodes, here's what the documentation suggests: https://longhorn.io/docs/1.2.4/advanced-resources/deploy/customizing-default-settings/